# How to add at run-time component (Compact Framework 3.5)?

Tags: compact-framework

I need to add at run-time component of the `PictureBox`.

There will be a few to several. How can I do it?

Programmers writing based on the `Compact Framework 3.5`.

Answer (score 1):

You would do it the same way that all controls are added.  In general it looks like this:

```
var newControl = new Control(); // or new PictureBox
// initialize properties like size, position, etc
myForm.Controls.Add(newControl);
```

A good way to see how this is done for different controls is to look at the designer-created conde for `InitializeComponents`, as it creates all of the controls and layout done in the designers at run time.